# Add custom meta box on Post page

Tags: plugins, customization, custom-field, metabox, options

I want add a new settings box on the *Post* page. I'd like to be under the category or above, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need  to use the [`add_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_meta_box' ) );
function my_custom_meta_box(){

  $args = array();

  add_meta_box(
    'my_metabox_id',
    __( 'My Meta Box', 'my_textdomain' ), // Title
    'my_callback_function',               // Callback function that renders the content of the meta box
    'post',                               // Admin page (or post type) to show the meta box on
    'side',                               // Context where the box is shown on the page
    'high',                               // Priority within that context
    $args                                 // Arguments to pass the callback function, if any
  );
}


function my_callback_function( $args ){

  //The markup for your meta box goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in you `function.php` file. The below code will create text box in post type "post". Only defining text field will not work you need to make it save too when post is saved. check below url for saving value of meta box.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add(){
  add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );}

function cd_meta_box_cb(){ 
  <label for="my_meta_box_text">Text Label</label>
  <input type="text" name="my_meta_box_text" id="my_meta_box_text" />
}
```

For more details visit http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336